# ¿Cómo eliminar diccionarios con valores 0 de una lista? Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una lista como esta:

```
bloqueOrdenApi = [{'Articulos': 0}, {'Libros': 0}, {'Proyectos': 5}, {'GradoAcademico': 7}, {'Capacitacion': 8}]
```

Estoy intentando eliminar los diccionarios cuyo valor es 0, en este caso Artículos y Libros, estoy haciendo esto:

```
for b in bloqueOrdenApi:
  for k, v in b.items():
    if v == 0:
      del bloqueOrdenApi[v]
print(bloqueOrdenApi)
```

Pero obtengo como salida esto:

```
bloqueOrdenApi = [{'Libros': 0}, {'Proyectos': 5}, {'GradoAcademico': 7}, {'Capacitacion': 8}]
```

Solamente se me borra el elemento Artículos y Libros no. ¿Cómo puedo eliminar todos los diccionarios que tienen como valor 0? Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo no recomiendo utilizar `del` para eliminar elementos de una lista, en su lugar utiliza el método `pop()`, pues `del` se utiliza para otras cosas.

Tu error es que siempre eliminas el primer elemento, al hacer `del bloqueOrdenApi[v]` estas eliminando de la lista `bloqueOrdenApi` el elemento `v` que por tu `if` siempre valdrá `0`. Otra cosa es que al eliminar el elemento el próximo será omitido, esto por que, por ejemplo, si el elemento `0` es eliminado el siguiente es el elemento `1` y el que ahora ocupa la posición `1` es el que anteriormente era el segundo.

Creo que una forma de evitar confusiones es utilizando una comprensión de lista.

```py
bloqueOrdenApi = [e for e in bloqueOrdenApi if list(e.values()) != [0]]
print(bloqueOrdenApi)
```

Aquí solo obtenemos los valores y dado que el resultado es un `dict_values()` lo convertiremos a lista con `list()` y esta vez comparamos con `[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Exacto la respuesta de Christian tiene toda la razón, yo cree una función que para no eliminar el primer indice hice una repeticion según la longitud de la lista:

```
def arreglo(lista):
  for j in range(0,len(lista)):
    for b in lista:
      for k, v in b.items():
        if v == 0:  del lista[v]
  return lista
```

Pero indudablemente el código de Chistian es lo que refleja la simpleza de python.
Muy buena Christian. Un saludo a todos

Comment: Pues hola! Existen varias formas de resolver un problema y la tuya es otra de ellas, hacer un ciclo es muy costoso para una máquina, ahora imagínate hacerlo 3 veces :/

Comment: Si estas de acuerdo con una respuesta es bueno votarla a favor, de esa forma indicas que la respuesta vale la pena :D

Comment: Correcto, tienes toda la razón, un saludo.